# Splitting of Irreducible character when restricted to index $2$ subgroup over finite field

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

In Exercise $15$ of chapter 2 of the book "The symmetric group" by B.E. Sagan, I can prove the following

Let $G$ be finite group and $H$ be an index $2$ subgroup. If $\chi$ is an irreducible character of $G$, then $\chi|_H$ is irreducible iff $\chi(g) \neq 0$ for some $g \not\in H$.

This is proved using character theory over $\mathbb{C}$ and the fact that a conjugacy class of  an element $h\in G$ in $H$ is as same as that of $G$ or splits in two conjugacy classes of same size.

Can this be proved for a finite field of characteristic $p$ as well, when $p\nmid |G|$?

Comment: I think you might need the field to be a splitting field for the group. For example, $G=S_3$ has a faithful irreducible representation of degree $2$ over ${\mathbb F}_5$, and its restriction to $H=A_3$ is irreducible, but the trace of the images of all elements of $G \setminus H$ is $0$. (The problem here is arising from the fact that the restriction to $H$ is not absolutely irreducible.)

Comment: @DerekHolt The same problem happens in characteristic $0$ if you consider real representations instead of complex representations.

Comment: @MathMo Yes that's true, but the question was whether a result that holds for complex representations holds also for representations over finite fields, and the answer is no in general, but I think it's yes for algebraically closed finite fields. There is the additional complication that the standard generalization of characters to finite fields is by means of Brauer characters.

Comment: In my answer, I took character to mean trace of a representation. I definitely agree  with you that the field needs to be large enough!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general result and holds at least when the characteristic is large enough ($p\nmid |G|$ makes no difference).

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $\ne 2$. Let $\rho\colon G\to \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ be an irreducible representation. Let $\chi\colon G\to k^\times$ be the representation $G\to G/H\cong\{\pm 1\}\subset k^\times$ (so we need $\mathrm{char}\ k\ne 2$). The following are equivalent:

1. $\rho|_H$ is reducible
2. $\rho\otimes \chi\cong\rho$

If the second condition is true, then $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)(g) = \chi(g)\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)(g)=-\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)(g) = 0$ for all $g\in G\setminus H$.

Conversely, suppose that $\mathrm{char}\ k\ge n!$ so that $\rho$ is determined by its trace (you can probably get around this by playing with the entire characteristic polynomial). If $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)(g) = 0$ for all $g\in G\setminus H$, then $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)(g) = \chi(g)\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)(g)$ for all $g$ (if $g\in H$, then $\chi(g) = 1$, and if $g\notin H$, then both sides are $0$), so $\rho\cong\rho\otimes \chi$.

To prove the equivalence of $1$ and $2$:

- If $\rho|_H$ is reducible then let $\sigma$ be a subrepresentation of minimal dimension. By Frobenius reciprocity,
  $$(\rho, \mathrm{Ind}_H^G\sigma) = (\rho|_H, \sigma) \ge 1.$$
  Since $\rho$ is irreducible and by dimension counting, by Schur's lemma $\rho\cong \mathrm{Ind}_H^G\sigma$. But since $\rho|_H \cong (\rho\otimes\chi)|_H$, the same argument shows that $\rho\otimes\chi\cong \mathrm{Ind}_H^G\sigma$. So $\rho\cong\rho\otimes\chi$.
- If $\rho\cong\rho\otimes\chi$, suppose that $\rho|_H$ is irreducible. By Frobenius reciprocity and Schur's lemma,
  $$(\rho, 
  \mathrm{Ind}^G_H\rho|_H) = (\rho|_H, \rho|_H) = 1$$
  so $\rho$ is a subrepresentation of $\mathrm{Ind}^G_H\rho|_H$. Write $\mathrm{Ind}^G_H\rho|_H = \rho \oplus \rho'$ with $\rho'\ne \rho$. So there exists $g\in G\setminus H$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho(g))\ne \mathrm{Tr}(\rho'(g))$. But since $H\lhd G$, we have $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{Ind}^G_H\rho|_H(g))=0$. So
  $$\mathrm{Tr}(\rho(g)) + \mathrm{Tr}(\rho'(g))=0.$$
  In particular, $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho(g)) \ne 0$, contradicting $\rho\cong\rho\otimes\chi$.

Comment: Thank you so much. When you say "suppose that char ≥!, so that $\rho$ is determined by its trace" , what exactly do you mean?